# Preventing access to subsequent pages not proceeding current

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, session, access-control

I have a codeigniter MVC setup where a piece of a form exists on one page.

Each time the user clicks the submit button, the same controller loads the next piece of the form under the same url `http://domain.com/form` and using the same view but with different data (the data in this case is the form elements).

**Objective:**

1) Make sure the next piece that gets loaded is the correct proceeding piece. *Remember, I'm using the same controller under the same URL and I am using the same view, just with different initialization data each time a new one needs to be populated.*

2) Restrict the user from jumping to a form piece that does not directly proceed one he is currently on

What is the best way to accomplish this? I would like to use sessions and I would like to not use hidden input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
// load first form data here, then: 
$data = '...';

// this is intentionally above the first form
if ($this->session->userdata('step_1') == 'done' AND is post action) {
   if(the second form is validated, then) {
       // unset the session here
       $this->session->unset_userdata('step_1');
   }
}

if ($this->session->userdata('step_1')!=='done' AND is post action ) {
    if(the first form validates here, then) {
       $this->session->set_userdata('step_1', 'done');
       // prepare the second form data here, that will override the one above:
       $data = '...';
    }
}
```

Please note, i don't use CI for a while now so i don't really remember all the object names out there, but you should get the point.

Comment: Hi, how can this be accomplished `the first form is validated`? The only way I could think of is to set a hidden input on form 1 with a key. But this is the kind of thing I want to avoid. If validation relies on a post action then a user can simulate a post request to my server with a post body containing `this is the first form you can trust me` or `i'm the last form go ahead and post this incomplete data to your databse moahahahahah`.

Comment: please see my edited answer, it should be clear now how to see if the first form has been marked as validated or not.